# GroupLayout z-order

Tags: java, javafx, z-order, grouplayout

everybody! I have problems with drawing my components in z-order using GroupLayout. My button works not stable (dissapears for ex. if mouse was moved). What's this? Errors in drawing?
This is code to set z-order.

```
        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = (javax.swing.GroupLayout) jLayeredPane1.getLayout();//new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    //getContentPane().setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    //jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(100, 100, 100)
            .addComponent(jPanel2)
            .addContainerGap(211, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(110, 110, 110)
            .addComponent(btn1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(100, 100, 100)
            .addComponent(jPanel2)
            .addContainerGap(33, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(110, 110, 110)
            .addComponent(btn1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jPanel2, 1);
    jLayeredPane1.setLayer(btn1, 2);
```

This is code all code of frame

```
package examples;   
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
//import javax.swing.SpringLayout;

public class BrowserFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public BrowserFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initAndShowGUI() {
        // This method is invoked on the EDT thread
        //JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing and JavaFX");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        //FlowLayout fLayout = new FlowLayout();

        final JPanel jPanel2 = new JPanel();


        /*getContentPane().setLayout(fLayout);*/
        jPanel2.add(fxPanel);

        final JButton btn1 = new JButton();
        btn1.setText("test");
        //btn1.setBounds(110, 140, 150, 160);


        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = (javax.swing.GroupLayout) jLayeredPane1.getLayout();//new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        //getContentPane().setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        //jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(100, 100, 100)
                .addComponent(jPanel2)
                .addContainerGap(211, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(110, 110, 110)
                .addComponent(btn1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(100, 100, 100)
                .addComponent(jPanel2)
                .addContainerGap(33, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(110, 110, 110)
                .addComponent(btn1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jPanel2, 1);
        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(btn1, 2);


        //this.add(jPanel2);

        //jPanel2.setBounds(100, 120, 400, 550);
        //jLayeredPane1.add(jPanel2, new Integer(1));


        //jLayeredPane1.add(btn1, new Integer(2));
        //jLayeredPane1.setLayer(btn1, 2);
        /*jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(100, 100, 100)
                .addComponent(btn1)
                .addContainerGap(211, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(100, 100, 100)
                .addComponent(btn1)
                .addContainerGap(33, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );    */


        //jLayeredPane1.add(btn1, new Integer(2));
        //jLayeredPane1.add(btn1, new Integer(1));
        //jPanel2.add(btn1);
        //jLayeredPane1.add(btn1);

        /*jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(jPanel2Layout);*/

        /*jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(120, 120, 120)
                .addComponent(btn1)
                .addContainerGap(211, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(120, 120, 120)
                .addComponent(btn1)
                .addContainerGap(33, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );*/

        /*jLayeredPane1.setComponentZOrder(jPanel2, 2);
        jLayeredPane1.setComponentZOrder(btn1, 1);*/
        //jLayeredPane1.setComponentZOrder(jButton1, 2);
        //this.add(btn1);
        /*getContentPane().setComponentZOrder(btn1, 1);
        getContentPane().setComponentZOrder(jPanel2, 0);*/
        this.pack();
        this.setSize(640, 480);


        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            initFX(fxPanel);
        });
    }

    private WebView webView;

    private void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        // This method is invoked on the JavaFX thread
        Scene scene = createScene();
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }

    private Scene createScene() {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.load("http://www.ya.ru");
        root.getChildren().add(webView);
        root.toBack();
        return scene;
    }    

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLayeredPane1 = new javax.swing.JLayeredPane();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jButton1, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jPanel1, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jLayeredPane1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jLayeredPane1);
        jLayeredPane1.setLayout(jLayeredPane1Layout);
        jLayeredPane1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jLayeredPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jLayeredPane1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(306, 306, 306)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(277, 277, 277))
        );
        jLayeredPane1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jLayeredPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(72, 72, 72)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(280, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLayeredPane1)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLayeredPane1)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BrowserFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BrowserFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BrowserFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BrowserFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //new BrowserFrame().setVisible(true);
                new BrowserFrame().initAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLayeredPane jLayeredPane1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

If I don't use `GroupLayout` everything works, but I need relative positions of components.

Comment: TL;DR  Try creating a [mcve] ... with emphasis on minimal.  If you can reproduce the issue on a small test case, the problem may become obvious.

Comment: Wait!  Why are you using both *swing* and *javafx* at the same time???  Pick one.

Comment: I wanted to create Swing Application using NetBeans GUI Builder, but I needed browser inside my app, I haven't find swing browser example, only javafx-based. That' why I tried to set javafx panel inside swing app.

Comment: See [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) and [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)

Answer (score 0):

I got answer in [javatalks.ru](http://javatalks.ru/topics/50236?page=1#251918). Simply add transparent panel above the browser panel.

```
package name.wind.common.fx;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        buttonPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        JButton button1st = new JButton("button1st");
        button1st.setEnabled(false);
        buttonPanel.add(button1st);
        JButton button2nd = new JButton("button2nd");
        button2nd.setEnabled(false);
        buttonPanel.add(button2nd);

        JFXPanel browserPanel = new JFXPanel();
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            WebView webView = new WebView();
            WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
            webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
                (ov, oldState, newState) -> {
                    if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                            button1st.setEnabled(true);
                            button2nd.setEnabled(true);
                        });
                    }
                });
            webEngine.load("http://www.ya.ru");
            StackPane root = new StackPane();
            root.getChildren().add(webView);
            browserPanel.setScene(new Scene(root));
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new OverlayLayout(frame.getContentPane()));
        frame.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(browserPanel);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```